# PasswordGenerator package is generating unwanted special char

Tags: c#, string, special-characters, backslash, password-generator

I'm using the [PasswordGenerator(2.05)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PasswordGenerator/) package in order to generate password.

One of the methods allows me to choose which special characters I can include.

Here is my code:

```
public static string GetUniquePassword(
        int i_lengthOfPassword = 8,
        bool i_includeLowercase = true, 
        bool i_includeUppercase = true, 
        bool i_includeNumeric = true,
        bool i_includeSpecial = true)
    {
        var pwd = new Password(includeLowercase: i_includeLowercase,
                               includeUppercase: i_includeUppercase,
                               includeNumeric: i_includeNumeric,
                               includeSpecial: i_includeSpecial,
                               passwordLength: i_lengthOfPassword).IncludeSpecial("!@#$%^&*,");

        string passwordResult = pwd.Next();
        return passwordResult;
    }
```

The actual result is that once in a while I'm getting a password that includes the special character `\` which my app doesn't allow.

For instance : `2\8$Y!f0`.

I'll be happy if the generator won't include this character.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: generate a much longer password, remove offending characters and cut down to size?

Comment: Looking at the source of the project here https://github.com/prjseal/PasswordGenerator/ - no there is no workaround. You could either rebuild it your own, implementing an Exclude method or contact the creator to do so.
Of course you could simply replace all "\" occurrences in the result string with a random character.

Comment: @Flo There is a solution. I've provided it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not reading the [code](https://github.com/prjseal/PasswordGenerator/blob/master/PasswordGenerator/Password.cs#L98-L102) incorrectly, you actually want this:

```cs
IPassword pwd = new Password(includeLowercase: i_includeLowercase,
                       includeUppercase: i_includeUppercase,
                       includeNumeric: i_includeNumeric,
                       includeSpecial: false,
                       passwordLength: i_lengthOfPassword);

if (i_includeSpecial)
{
    pwd = pwd.IncludeSpecial("!@#$%^&*,");
}
```

You need to set `includeSpecial` to false in the `Password` constructor, otherwise the [constructor of `PasswordSettings`](https://github.com/prjseal/PasswordGenerator/blob/f86da8e021c3f0f47b5a120c404e1df27106ca99/PasswordGenerator/PasswordSettings.cs#L18) (which it calls) will have already added all the usual special characters.

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/73S6qP)